# Unit testing in BASH (checking script output)

Tags: bash, unit-testing

How to automate checking of the script output in BASH? 
For example if I wanted student to write a command and then check if the ouput of the command is what my predefined command is set to produce.
Br, mika

Comment: show us sample of input and output.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a starting point:

```
unit_test(){
    local expected="$1"; shift
    local real="$(${@})"
    if  [[ $real != $expected ]]; then
        echo "real=$real != expected=$expected"
    fi
}

unit_test "Hello world" echo "hello world"
```

Check this : https://github.com/kward/shunit2